# Plotting from dataset in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This must be very simple but i am not able to figure out how to do it.I am trying to plot the data present in my dataset.

Below is my code ,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_csv('TipsReceivedPerMeal.csv')
plt.scatter(dataset[0],dataset[1])
plt.show()
```

The data in my CSV file is some random data, which specifies what tip a waiter receive at one particular day.

Data in CSV

```
MealNumber  TipReceived
1                    17
2                    10
3                    5
4                    7
5                    14
6                    25
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: what about `dataset.plot(x='MealNumber', y = 'TipReceived' ..., kind='scatter`). You might want to have a look at searborns facetgrid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to replace 
`plt.scatter(dataset[0],dataset[1])` 
with

```
plt.scatter(dataset[[0]],dataset[[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace:
`plt.scatter(dataset[0],dataset[1])`

With:
`plt.scatter(dataset['MealNumber'],dataset['TipReceived'])`

In Pandas columns can either be referenced by name or by column number with iloc.

Comment: Mind that `dataset.iloc[0]` won't work, you'd need `dataset.iloc[:,0]` instead.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, thanks for the comment. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, some already mentionned in previous answers,

1. `plt.scatter(dataset['MealNumber'],dataset['TipReceived'])` (as mentioned by @Ankit Malik)
2. `plt.scatter(dataset.iloc[:,0],dataset.iloc[:,1])`
3. `plt.scatter(dataset[[0]],dataset[[1]])` (as mentioned by @Miriam)

In order for those to work with the data from the question, one should use the `delim_whitespace=True` paramter, as otherwise the read-in would not work:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('TipsReceivedPerMeal.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
```