# Plot data with different types of values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, dataset

[image]

All the data points are in blue color. I want the data points with ID- 0000 on the y-axis to be different color.

I want to plot a dataset as below in python:

```
Timestamp   ID
0.0000      0000
0.000271    0080
0.000495    0000
0.000736    0081
0.000983    0000
0.001239    0165
0.001484    0000
0.001736    018f
0.001984    0000
0.002229    02a0
0.002465    0000
0.002654    02b0
0.002915    0000
0.003143    0316
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777946/plotting-from-dataset-in-python).

Comment: have you tried the most obvious `df.plot()` ...

Comment: @VasilisG. Hi, I already tried that but no plot is shown in output. Also, there is no error but the output is blank.

Comment: @RafaelC it worked, thanks to both. But the values of ID are not shown along y-axis. What can I do for that ?

Comment: Your IDs are some strings, not just numbers. What output plot do you expect?

Comment: @Bazingaa Hi, thank you for trying to help. My plot is made. Can you help me in specifying different color to '0000' field in ID column.

Comment: What do you mean by specifying color to `0000`? Plz share the output you got and the output you want

Comment: @Bazingaa All of my data points are in blue color. I want to give different color to the data points with '0000' ID value as shown above in the dataset.

Comment: @Lovleen could you include the code which gives the plot? It is not clear what information the color will encode... What is the wanted color for id different than `0000`?

Comment: @xdze2 Hi, I have added the image and written what I want to do.

Comment: @Lovleen How did you manage to create that plot in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Numpy and Matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

timestamp = np.linspace(0, 1, 7)
ID = np.array(['0000', '0080', '0000', '018f', '0uu00', 'hello', '0000'])
zero_points = (ID == '0000')  # define a selection mask
non_zero_points = np.logical_not(zero_points)

plt.plot(timestamp[non_zero_points],  ID[non_zero_points], 'bo', label='not 0000')
plt.plot(timestamp[zero_points],  ID[zero_points], 'ro', label='0000')
plt.xlabel('time'); plt.ylabel('values'); plt.legend();
```

which gives:

[image: example graph]

The idea is to create a boolean array which is later use to select each group of points. (There is maybe better way to write this, for instance by setting a color value for each point in a scatter plot...)